# A file is being http posted, how can I reference the parameter by index?

Tags: java, xml, spring

An XML file is being posted to a url that my spring mvc is responding to.

In .NET, I could do this:

```
request.Form[0]
request.Form["abc"]
```

or

```
request.QueryString[0]
request.QueryString["some_key"]
```

Now with spring/servlets it seems I can only do this:

```
request.getParameter("some_key")
```

or get all the names or values.

When someone is posting a file to a url, using http post, won't this be just a single request parameter then?

Can I get the parameter using index with servlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When someone is posting a file to a url, using http post, won't this be just a single request parameter then?

Not necessarily. If the form contains more fields, then we'd have more parameters.

> Can I get the parameter using index with servlets?

AFAIK, No. `request.getParameter()` doesn't return an array or a collection. So can't do that with `request.getParameter()`

`request.getParameterValues(String)` returns an array - but only the values associated with the given parameter name

`request.getParameterMap()` works on keys, and not ordered. That won't help either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using annotation based Spring controllers then this should work :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload.view")
public ModelAndView upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile f) {
  if (f == null) {
    return new ModelAndView("upload", "msg", "The file is null.");
  }

  return new ModelAndView("upload", "msg", "File ( " + f.getOriginalFilename() + ") successfully uploaded.");
}
```

Additionally you need to add this to your application context

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.C ommonsMultipartResolver">
  <!-- Max size in bytes. -->
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

if you are using the old style controllers then you can do what is suggested in the Spring documentation (but it is more complex) http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s08.html